# Nokogiri raises error when parsing html with <meta charset='UTF-8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html-parsing, nokogiri

Nokogiri::HTML raises error when I add `<meta charset='UTF-8>` to a .html file.

The file is the following one:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My super content</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <footer>
      <p></p>
    </footer>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./static.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

When I parse it I get:

```sh
$ doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('myfile.html'))
$ doc.errors
> [#<Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError: 10:12: ERROR: Tag footer invalid>]
```

Removing `<meta charset="UTF-8">` fix the problem.

Why? And how can I make it works with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nokogiri is primarily an XML parser and thus expects mostly valid XML. Although HTML looks a lot like XML, especially with HTML 5, there are different rules about e.g. closing tags and algorithms to detect things such as encoding which makes HTML 5 incompatible to XML and XML parsers.

In [an issue](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1008#issuecomment-278904205) related to your problem, the response of Mike Dalessio (one of the nokogiri maintainers) was accordingly:

> Nokogiri does not support HTML5. You may want to check out the [Nokogumbo](https://github.com/rubys/nokogumbo) project, which aims for HTML5 compatibility with the [Gumbo](https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser#readme) parser.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/2064